# How to add space between two list columns in SharePoint Designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list in SharePoint and two of the columns contain numerical and text data.  The numerical data is aligned right and the text, left so they are very close together and I would like to add space between them.

I opened the list in SharePoint designer and tried to add padding to the right of the numerical column but this only appears to adjust the heading.  I even opened up the list in code view and anywhere I saw padding tried to test it out but nowhere does it actually put padding in for the whole column.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might get more answers to this question over on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I might but I doubt I would understand them :(